# how to refresh all worksheets automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have one workbook containing 7 worksheets, first one contains the data from which other sheets are created by using power query, I want to refresh them all after every 10 seconds or if there is some change in the data in sheet1, which can be done manually by using `ctrl+alt+f5` i.e refreshall button

so my question is

1. how to refresh all worksheets in current workbook after every 10 seconds using macro

**edit**

```
i tried this code

Public interval As Double

Sub macro_timer()

    interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

    Application.OnTime interval, "my_macro"

End Sub


Sub my_macro()

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Call macro_timer

End Sub
```

workbook refreshes one time and after 10 seconds i get following error
i have enables macros from macros settings and also allowed trust access to vba project object model still i get same error
[image]

Comment: Do you have this in a sheet module or an inserted module. Did you rename said module that has the same name as your macro? How are you initiating the macro to run? Have you tried googling the error and attempting resolutions suggested in other questions about this error?
Another potential way could be insert a new module and move the code into that one then delete the old one.

Comment: 1) have this in a sheet module 2)  how i initiate -> view macros-> select macro that i want to run-> click run 3) googled the error, resolution mentioned in last two lines of question, which didnt work in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Public interval As Double

Sub macro_t()

    interval = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.OnTime interval, "macro_t"

End Sub
```